# Combining IF with AVG in mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'd like to calculate the average of a column based on an if condition, but I'm getting stuck because, if a value is within a certain range, I'd like to set it to something else for the purposes of calculating the average.

Basically, I've tried variations of the following:

SELECT avg(IF(CAST(value AS SIGNED)<550, value, 100)) AS output...

In other words, I want to include only the values that are less than 550 as part of the average, otherwise return 100 for that cell as part of the average. So if I had the following values:

150, 200, 600, 650

then the query would calculate the average of these values:

100, 100, 600, 650.

Is there any way that this can be achieved? Aside from variations of the query above which don't seem to work, I've tried using an intermediate step that creates a new column of the actual values that need to be entered into the average, but this seems to be making the query much slower to execute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just turn the `IF` around...,

```
SELECT AVG(IF(CAST(value AS SIGNED) < 550, 100, value)) AS output...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
AVG(CASE WHEN value < 550 THEN 100 ELSE value END)
```

Comment: Ah, hadn't thought of using CASE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select avg(case when value < 550 then 100 else value end) as output...
```